# How to get contours that shape edges join together?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have a image, there have many square shape, I want to get those shape contours,but those shape edges join together,so I don't know how to separate edges.
Can someone have good ideas to get those contours use `opencv` ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may find contours with hierarchy using `RETR_TREE` and find the "inner contours" that doesn't have a child contour.

When using `RETR_TREE`, the empty contours has and outer contour and an inner contour.
The inner contours are separated, so finding only the inner contours solves the problem.

---

The following code sample uses the following stages:

- Convert the input image to binary image (using automatic binary thresholding).
- Find contours with hierarchy, using cv2.RETR_TREE
- Iterate the contours, and find contours without a child contours (according to the hierarchy): `if hierarchy[0][i][2] < 0` ...
- Draw the contours with different colors (just for showing that it's not one large contour).

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  # Used for a colormap

img = cv2.imread('shapes.png')  # Read input image.
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert to grayscale.
out = np.zeros_like(img)  # Prepare output image

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Convert to binary image - use automatic thresholding

# Find contours with hierarchy, use cv2.RETR_TREE
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get viridis colormap, and convert it to look up table:
cmap = plt.get_cmap('hsv')

# Iterate over the contours and their hierarchies
# Draw contours with different colors for marking that it's not one large contour
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    if hierarchy[0][i][2] < 0:
        color = np.round(np.array(cmap(i*57 % 255)[:-1])*255).astype(np.uint8) # Get the color from a colormap

        # If contour has no child, draw the contour
        cv2.drawContours(out, contours, i, tuple(color.tolist()), 3)

cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)  # Save the result.
```

---

Output:
[image]